# SQL: improving join efficiency

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

If I turn this sub-query which selects sales persons and their highest price paid for any item they sell:

```
select *,
    (select top 1 highestProductPrice
     from   orders o
     where  o.salespersonid = s.id
     order by highestProductPrice desc ) as highestProductPrice
from salespersons s
```

in to this join in order to improve efficiency:

```
select *, highestProductPrice
from   salespersons s join (
       select salespersonid, highestProductPrice, row_number(
           partition by salespersonid 
           order by salespersonid, highestProductPrice) as rank
       from orders ) o on s.id = o.salespersonid
```

It still touches every order record (it enumerates the entire table before filtering by salespersonid it seems.)  However you cannot do this:

```
select *, highestProductPrice
from   salespersons s join (
       select salespersonid, highestProductPrice, row_number(
           partition by salespersonid 
           order by salespersonid, highestProductPrice) as rank
       from orders 
       where orders.salepersonid = s.id) o on s.id = o.salespersonid
```

The where clause in the join causes a `multi-part identifier "s.id" could not be bound.

**Is there any way to join the top 1 out of each order group with a join but without touching each record in orders?**

Comment: What do you mean 'touches every record'?  It's going to have to touch every record **in order to figure out which one needs to be the top 1**.  If you don't have an *existing* index in your desired order, this has to be performed at runtime, every time (well, it might cache the answers, or build a re-usable temp index).

Comment: The query takes significantly less time to execute when you filter the enumeration to only the join-able records.  In other words, only rank the records I want to rank, and not rank the records that wouldn't join based on salespersonid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT
  S.*, 
  T.HighestProductPrice
FROM   
  SalesPersons S

  CROSS APPLY 
  (
    SELECT TOP 1 O.HighestProductPrice
    FROM Orders O
    WHERE O.SalesPersonid = S.Id
    ORDER BY O.SalesPersonid, O.HighestProductPrice DESC
  ) T
```

Comment: That's very interesting that it would allow the inner where condition to reference the outer table.  I will give that a try.

Comment: Can it really be more effecient than using a sub-select with ranking?

Answer (score 1):

would

```
select s.*, max(highestProductPrice)
   from salespersons s 
   join orders o on o.salespersonid = s.id
group by s.*
```

or

```
select s.*, highestProductPrice
   from salespersons s join (select salepersonid, 
                             max(highestProductPrice) as highestProductPrice
                             from orders o) as o on o.salespersonid = s.id
```

work?

Comment: I oversimplified the select.  The original contains a couple fields to find the lowest of the collection.  However, I could aggregate them in the Max() function.  I just wonder if selecting distinct on S.* would cause a more significant delay. +1 for being on the right track.